# PRAW connected Tkinter GUI appearing blank when I run code

Tags: python, tkinter, reddit, praw

I'm writing a program that connects to reddits API. I have three entry widgets set up for the user to input the a specific word, a specific subreddit, and a specific # of posts to parse.

Posted below is the code. I have all of it sitting within a class called KDGUI. When I run the script, I just get a blank, white Tkinter GUI screen.

Any ideas? I've tried tabbing the GUI code back and forth within the class. I'm not experienced enough to really figure this out yet.

Thanks!

This is on Sublime Text. I didn't post the API info, but imagine it's above the root variable.

```
root = tk.Tk()

Ht = 300
Wd = 450


class KDGUI():

    def enter_info():
        word = e1.get()
        subred = e2.get()
        amnt = e3.get()

        def run_bot():
            sub = r.subreddit(subred)
            time.sleep(1)
            print("---Grabbing subreddit---\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            subs = sub.top('day', limit=amnt)
            print("---Grabbing posts in sub---\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Looking for Articles..\n")

            word_not_found = True

            for posts in subs:
                article_url = posts.url
                post_title = posts.title
                word_to_find = word

                word_not_found = False

                if word_to_find in post_title:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print(post_title)
                    print('')



                else: 
                    word_not_found = word_not_found and True

                if word_not_found:
                    print("Can't find articles in the subreddit!")




        root.title("Finding Kawhi Articles")

        canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=Ht, width=Wd)
        canvas.pack()

        background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='Kawhi-Leonard.gif')

        background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
        background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        e1 = tk.Entry(root) # Word to enter
        e1.place(relx=.275, rely=.45)

        e2 = tk.Entry(root) # subreddit to enter
        e2.place(relx=.275, rely=.55)

        e3 = tk.Entry(root) # sort by amount of posts
        e3.place(relx=.275, rely=.65)

        activate_button = tk.Button(root, text="Click here to generate 
article!", command=run_bot)
        activate_button.place(relx=.20, rely=.85, relwidth=0.55, 
relheight=0.10)

        close_button = tk.Button(root, text="Click to close program", 
command = root.quit)
        close_button.place()

        root.resizable(False, False)





root.mainloop()
KDGUI()
```

Comment: Move `root.mainloop()` behind `KDGUI()`.

Comment: Behind the definition of the class or the call of the class? Because neither of those work for me, and I'm still receiving the same result. I really appreciate the response though!

Comment: Normally `root.mainloop() should` be the last line of your code.

Comment: Hmm, I understand now. I'm still getting the same result though. Just a blank white window.

Comment: Your class `KDGUI` has no initialiser, and you didn't call its method enter_info. So basically nothing got executed. If you have called it correctly, you should have received an unbound error.

Comment: I'm not too well versed in classes. Maybe I shouldn't be using one here. But to create an initializer for the class, I have to pass in parameters. Are these parameters just the methods that exist in my class?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. Why do you need to pass parameters for initialiser? Also you can do without initialiser.